# A monolithic group (singular agreement)

Tags: ielts

I downloaded the old ielts test and its keys, one of the questions asked you to describe a bar chart, and there were 3 different pieces of data given on the chart:

- Cars owners
- Internet users
- Apartment renters

[image: The graph shows average data for 3 cities in 2005. The figures are for millions of people.]

In its key for this question, there was a line which I thought it was weird.

> The line stated:
>
> > *"Internet users* ***was*** *the highest statistic."*

Is it supposed to use the word **"were"** instead?

*Or* ***"Internet users"*** was some kind of ***`singular agreement`*** for this case?

Comment: I would not use plural here (and I am British, and so favour the plural for group entities like governments and teams). The reason, I believe, is that "Internet users" is here a kind of name: it is not saying anything about internet users (people who use the internet) but about "internet users" (a dataset labelled "internet users").

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way of describing such language use is to wrap a word or phrase:

- {Internet users} is...
- {Internet user}s are...

So while the data is describing the number of individual Internet users etc., the statistics compare three singular groups that happen to be labelled 'car owners', 'Internet users' and 'Apartment renters'.

A classic example of such verb use involves "the family is" and "the family are", depending on whether we consider the family as a single unit or a group of individuals.